# Running iframe with large application in background without affecting main application,

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, html5-canvas, web-worker

The current application am working on needs another application to be loaded inside the app using iframe during app initilization. We are able to load the another app inside Iframe properly during app init but loading both apps simultaneously during load making the app to load very slow and page is freezing for some time.

**Issue we found:** The application we are loading inside Iframe sending lot of http requests and it is blocking our app. (more 6 requests per instance in browser)

Is there any way we can load app in iframe using **webworker** or any other technologies in multi threaded environment.

Answer (score 1):

iFrames usually run in the same thread/process as the main page.

Please read -> 
[Execute web worker from different origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913673/execute-web-worker-from-different-origin)